# Empty values entered into database when browser is refreshed

Tags: php

I have a user class that match all name attributes from a form with their input values, and then enter them into an array when submit button is clicked. These key=>values are then entered into the database using PDO.

When I run the code, empty values are inserted into the database. No error shows on the screen.

Where could the problem be?

```
<?php
```

require_once ('db.php');

```
class Users{

    public    $dbh;
    public    $table = "users";
    public    $data = array();
    public    $cols;
    public    $values;
    public    $valid_keys = array("name", "firstname", "email", "office");

    public function reg_user($data) {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            ksort($_POST);
            ksort($this->valid_keys);
            $dataDB = array();

        $this->data = $_POST;
        $this->pop_submit = array_pop($this->dataDB);

        $this->cols    =  '`'.implode('`, `', array_keys($this->dataDB)).'`' ;
        $this->values  = ':' . implode(", :", array_keys($this->dataDB));
        }
        //return $this->cols ."<br />".$this->values;
        $db = new  db;
        try{
        $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO $this->table ($this->cols ) VALUES ($this->values)");
        foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($k,$this->valid_keys)) {
                $dataDB[$k] = $v;
            $stmt -> bindValue(':'.$k, $v);
        }
    }
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = new Errors();
        echo "<b>".$error->displayError($e)."</b>";
    }
    }
}
?>

<form  action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" >  
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="office">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**Edit**

I added a new property `$valid_keys` to check for only specified keys to use in bind statement.

When I run the code above(with the edits), `Submit` is entered in all 4 columns, rather the inputs that was supplied.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I will make necessary cleanup on $_POST variables.

Comment: this is not about variables rather about keys, which you are adding to the query directly

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can you please provide an example of these ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have removed submit from array by using array_pop()

Comment: When I print_r values and col, submit do not show up

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've just notived and removed my previous comment

Comment: `implode('`, `', array_keys($_POST))` is an example

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can you please explain how I can solve this. My thought was that binding values from user inputs before executing will stop SQL Injection.

Comment: binding **values** will stop injection indeed. But beside binding values you are adding other query parts

Comment: SQL injection will be stopped for values but not for keys. You should for example create array of valid keys and allow only those from form which are in your array

Comment: Before executing command try to display query and run it in your database (for example in phpmyadmin) to ensure query will normally work. You should run echo $stmt->queryString; die();

Comment: Query now works, but the problem is that `Submit` is the only word inserted across all the four columns. Then, empty values are entered when I refresh the page

Comment: Come on, you edited this question completely, making totally different one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I updated the question with updates as they were solved. Was that the reason for the down vote ??

Comment: @dotman14 which downvote? Your question wasn't downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$dataDB = array();

foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  if (in_array($k,$this->valid_keys)) {
     $dataDB[$k] = $v;
  }
}
```

and from this moment instead of operating on $_POST you should operate only on $dataDB

So your code should be:

```
<?php
require_once ('db.php');

class Users{

    public    $dbh;
    public    $table = "users";
    public    $data = array();
    public    $cols;
    public    $values;
    public    $valid_keys = array("name", "firstname", "email", "office");

    public function reg_user($data) {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            $dataDB = array();

            foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
              if (in_array($k,$this->valid_keys)) {
                 $dataDB[$k] = $v;
              }
            }



        $this->cols    =  '`'.implode('`, `', array_keys($dataDB)).'`' ;
        $this->values  = ':' . implode(", :", array_keys($dataDB));

        //return $this->cols ."<br />".$this->values;
        $db = new  db;
        try{
        $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO $this->table ($this->cols ) VALUES ($this->values)");
        foreach ($dataDB as $k => $v) {

            $stmt -> bindValue(':'.$k, $v);

        }
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = new Errors();
        echo "<b>".$error->displayError($e)."</b>";
    }
    }
   }
}
?>

<form  action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" >  
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="office">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

If keys in input form and database would be different the code should look like:

```
<?php
require_once ('db.php');

class Users{

    public    $dbh;
    public    $table = "users";
    public    $data = array();
    public    $cols;
    public    $values;
    public    $valid_keys = array("name" => 'db_name', "firstname" => 'db_firstname', "email" => 'db_email', "office" => "db_office");

    public function reg_user($data) {
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            $dataDB = array();
            $fieldsDB = array();

            foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
                if (isset($this->valid_keys[$k])) {                  
                 $dataDB[$k] = $v;
                 $fieldsDB[] = $this->valid_keys[$k];
              }
            }



        $this->cols    =  '`'.implode('`, `', array_values($fieldsDB)).'`' ;
        $this->values  = ':' . implode(", :", array_keys($dataDB));

        //return $this->cols ."<br />".$this->values;
        $db = new  db;
        try{
        $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO $this->table ($this->cols ) VALUES ($this->values)");
        foreach ($dataDB as $k => $v) {

            $stmt -> bindValue(':'.$k, $v);

        }
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = new Errors();
        echo "<b>".$error->displayError($e)."</b>";
    }
    }
   }
}
?>

<form  action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" >  
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="office">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: This piece of code inserts the right values into the database, but I still have empty values when I refresh the page. Any idea why this is ?

Comment: But where you have empty values? In database or in form or just echoing them in php ?

Comment: Empty values are inserted into database when I refresh the page.

Comment: The code above only works when I move the foreach loop inside the second foreach that prepares the query for binding....Like I have it above

Comment: Have you copied this code at all and check it when you submit form? Your code above is not the same as I show in answer

Comment: The updated code works very well.
can you please explain why you removed the ksort(); why I initially added is because, input fields in forms may not necessarily match cols/keys in the bind statement. Are these match ups automatically done ?
Thank you

Comment: I've added another possible solution to answer in that case

Comment: Thank you for the update. How is this more efficient than using ksort();. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I simple don't see any point in sorting anything in this case

Answer (score 0):

You should validate that the post array contains the entries you require it to have(non-empty values).

Additionally to the validation of keys presented in @marcin-nabialek answer you should validate your values.

e.g.:

```
<?php
$errors = [];
foreach($dataDB as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value) || someValidationFunction($value) === false) {
        $errors[] = sprintf('%s field was empty or invalid. "%s" is not a valid value for that field', $key, $value);
    }
}

if(!empty($errors)) {
    // do something with the errors here(display a notification to the user) and end the script.
    exit;
}
```